# How to implement interface, but publish new API?

Tags: go

How does one implement an interface but forbid users from calling the functions that implement that interface?

For example, we have a module that implements some interface `I` which has a required function to implement `Bar`:

```
//mymodule.go
import (I)

type Foo struct {
}

func (f *Foo) Bar(
      ...
      // DONT want users calling this directly
      // I.Bar eventually calls this   
) // dictated by I

func (f *Foo) BarCallMe() {
    ...
    I.Bar(f)
}

F = Foo{}
F.Bar() // make this not possible, do not want!
F.BarCallMe() // $PROFIT
```

How do we prevent a user of mymodule from using `Bar()` directly like `f.Bar()`? Meaning, if we want users of this module to only call `BarCallMe` how do we hide `Bar`?

More generically, how do you implement one interface but publish another?

Concrete example: Recently I implemented golang's heap interface which requires `Push` and `Pop` be implemented by the implementor. However, `heap.Push` calls your `Push` (https://golang.org/src/container/heap/heap.go?s=1949:1986#L42), so if a user called my `Push` directly, it would not have the intended result. So the question here is how to publish a `Push` that users call, while still providing a `Push` that meets the interface reqs.

Comment: I don' t know how feasible this would be in your case, but you could implement `Foo.BarCallMe`, then `typedef foo Foo` and implement `foo.Bar`, and convert between the two as necessary.

Comment: I think this is not possible, if it is an interface of another package. Because the method and all input and output types need to be exported. Also why implement a method, which gives you an error/panic if it is called directly? Could be a bad code smell.

Comment: @apxp I gave a concrete example. The heap's `push` method calls your `push` implementation but it also calls `up`, see here: https://golang.org/src/container/heap/heap.go?s=1949:1986#L42. If a user calls your `push` method directly, it won't have the desired effect. So, you need a user facing function that calls `heap.Push`

Comment: Don't export the methods you don't want people to use.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply you can't. If you don't provide all of the methods in the interface, then you don't implement the interface, and if the interface requires that the methods are exported (which it must, because you're using it from another package), then those methods have to be public. No amount of playing around with anonymous embedding or new type names is going to change the fact that **if you want your user to be able to pass something to `heap.Pop`, it must have a `Pop()` that they can call.** If you create something that doesn't have `Pop()` callable on it, then it isn't usable with the functions in `heap`, and won't be unless you provide some way to turn it into a `heap.Interface`, at which point the user will be able to call `Pop()` on it. This isn't unique to you, and it's fundamental to how the Go designers chose to make interfaces work. You can live with it (and trust your users not to deliberately break things), or you can choose not to use the containers in the standard library.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to say something like `InternalPop implements Pop` so that I can implement the required function but give it my own name, then define my own Pop. But, I trust that this answer is correct and so essentially I'm SOL.

Comment: I don’t understand how people “wrap” interfaces then where they utilize, but hide the internal interface.

Comment: @Tommy you can't do that using a single type. You have to use at least two types, one with the internal interface and one with the public one, and somehow consolidate the underlying implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an unexported type, and only implement the method on the "alias":

https://play.golang.org/p/ZHg2U1sbVwo

```
type Foo struct {}
type foo Foo

func (f *foo) Bar(
  ...
) // dictated by I

func (f Foo) BarCallMe() {
    ...
    I.Bar(foo(f))
}
```

Comment: `type foo Foo` does not declare a type alias, it declares a new type.

Comment: this golang doesn't really answer the question. The user has no way of calling `F.Foobar() where F is an instance of Foo`.